# In nested SQL how to sum group by values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an following SQL

```
SELECT MAX(o.tax) as tax_value 
FROM offer AS o 
WHERE o.status in (1) 
GROUP BY(o.offer_no)
```

Let say the above query return 3 records But I want to sum of these records inside another SQL

Let say

```
SELECT SUM(SELECT MAX(o.tax) as tax_value 
FROM offer AS o 
WHERE o.status in (1) 
GROUP BY(o.offer_no))  as created
```

But this gives me an error message. How can I solve this problem. I want to get sum of these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in a subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(tax_value)
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(tax) AS tax_value
    FROM offer
    WHERE status = 1
    GROUP BY offer_no) x
```

Comment: Yes it works now. I have one more qeustion that how can I sum these value in a single  SELECT statement without nesting inside SELECT.

Comment: You can't. You can only have one level of aggregation in a query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "table expression":

```
select sum(x.tax_value) as tax_value
from ( -- table expression here acts as a table
  SELECT MAX(o.tax) as tax_value 
  FROM offer AS o 
  WHERE o.status in (1) 
  GROUP BY(o.offer_no)
) x
```